# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader

Tags: java, android, opencv

i tried to load opencv library in java like

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("myopencv");
}
```

in setting.gradle

```
include ':libraries:opencvss'
```

where "myopencv" is library name in project.
Is it a correct way to load library in android studio or not?

so my issue is during run time while installing apk UnsatisfiedLinkError:
Here is my error log:

```
09-26 15:42:30.513 25824-25824/? E/OpenCV/StaticHelper: OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV       
09-26 15:42:30.533 25824-25824/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.myeffects, PID: 25824
                                               java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/mnt/asec/com.example.myeffects-1/pkg.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/mnt/asec/com.example.myeffects-1/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
                                                   at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
                                                   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:606)
                                                   at com.example.myeffects.CartoonifierView.<clinit>(CartoonifierView.java:262)
                                                   at com.example.myeffects.CartoonifierApp.onCreate(CartoonifierApp.java:68)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2305)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5295)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
                                                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: did you find a solution ? I have the same error.

Comment: no, not yet. still pending